# Wcf service seems to work correct from test client but not from application

Tags: c#, wcf, usb, mixed-mode

Currently I have a wcf-service that should do some work with an usb-device. The usb-connection itself is handled by some external mixed-mode libraries.
To get this working I made a function that changes the wcf-service during runtime to legacy mode.

If I test the service with the wcf Test-Client and call this method everything will run fine after that. But if I do the same calls from a custom client it won't. To be more specific I get communication errors with the usb-device on server side(okay, that's not very specific, I know, but that's all what I can get out of the external libraries).

So I'm pretty sure it's not a binding problem since I can call the functions of the wcf service itself and everything else works fine as long as I don't try to actually connect to the usb-device. Even the other methods of the external libraries work.

I really wonder what causes this problem and how to get rid of it :/

**Sidenote:** Client and wcf-service in c#, .NET4, mixed libraries compiled against .NET2.

Comment: Try perusing the Windows event logs. You should find an exception with a stack trace in there.

Comment: Did you analyze the traces.svclog file to figure out any thing interesting

Comment: How is the WCF service hosted, IIS, Windows Service, cmdline exe, etc ?

Comment: Thanks to traces I know now that the error comes out of a enumeration method 'xxxDevice.EnumerateDevices(xxxDevice*). But I don't know what to do with this information :/

Comment: @user957902 Currently it's hosted by Windows WCF-Host Service.

Comment: What type of error do you get when you call EnumerateDevices? Maybe it's just a permission problem.

Comment: @FlorianGerhardt its a CommunicationException from the external libraries and all it says is 'Error during communication to device.'
But I already had to figure out that these exceptions can be very misleading...for example as I remember the same error occured when I forgot to copy one of the mixed-mode assemblies :S

Comment: Also I'm not able to call this enumeration method directly since I can't access the namespace of it.

Comment: Meanwhile I'm pretty sure it's a permission problem. I don't really understand why, since the client and service are running on the same machine and account. But I tracked down the problem with the help of ILSpy down to a InitUsbDeviceNames-Method that either returns an 'usb-error' or doesn't find the libraries (there are other possible results, but the mentioned CommunicationException is thrown on these two results)

So in my oppinion the service has either not the rights to connect to usb or to read the needed libraries when connected with my own client.

But how to fix this? :S